# How do I add a hyper link to an image in a query slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I´m having trouble trying to add hyper links to the images in my slider.
I understand that images can´t be clickable in Jquery sliders therefore I have tried this in the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="items">
        <li>
          <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="slider-banner">
            <div class="imageLink" title="Click here to open google website." onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/'); return true;"></div>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
              <span>Click here to open google website.</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="slider-banner">
            <div class="imageLink" title="Click here to open yahoo website."  onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com'); return true;"></div>
            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">
              <span>Click here to open yahoo website.</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="slider-banner">
            <div class="imageLink" title="Click here to open Gmail website"  onclick="window.open('http://www.gmail.com/'); return true;"></div>
              <a href="http://www.gmail.com/">
                <span>Click here to open Gmail website.</span>
              </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
.imageLink {width: 950px;height: 400px;margin-top: -440px;cursor: pointer;}
```

Every time I save and preview no text appears nor images can be clicked inside the slider, as if the changes I made were literally invisible... 
I´m pretty sure its something really simple to solve but I can´t quite see what´s missing in the code.

here is the reference link of the website I´m modifying:
http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page149/progress

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "imageLink" class applied to the

```
 <a class="imageLink" href="http://www.gmail.com/">
```

unless you incorporate link style onto that css class as a subclass

not to complicate things, you need to have subclass in your css

```
.class1
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
.class1.img
{
define your style
```

}